# Unable to save images in Core Data

Tags: image, core-data

I am creating a student index app, in which you can save names, pictures and roles of students. Everything works just fine, but my code does not save images in my Core Data Model. I have been trying to figure it out the whole day.

You can find my whole project here: http://www21.zippyshare.com/v/26184330/file.html

```
#import "AddStudent.h"
#import "Studenten.h"
#import "Bild.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface AddStudent () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation AddStudent;
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize selectedBetreuungsgrund;
@synthesize studentBetrGrundCell = _studentBetrGrundCell;
@synthesize vorschauImageView = _vorschauImageView;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    _studentBetrGrundCell.textLabel.text = @"";
    _studentBetrGrundCell.delegate = self;
    _studentBetrGrundCell.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
- (void)betrGrundWasSelectedOnPicker:(Betreuungsgrund *)betreuungsgrund {

    self.selectedBetreuungsgrund = betreuungsgrund;
    _studentBetrGrundCell.textLabel.text = self.selectedBetreuungsgrund.name;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.studentNachnameTextfeld.delegate = self;
    self.studentVornameTextFeld.delegate = self;
    _studentNachnameTextfeld.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
    _studentVornameTextFeld.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [tgr setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender

{

        if (([_studentNachnameTextfeld.text isEqualToString:(@"")])||([_studentVornameTextFeld.text isEqualToString:(@"")])){
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Sie müssen alle Namensfelder ausfüllen!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else {

        Student *student = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student"
                                                             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        student.vorname = _studentVornameTextFeld.text;
        student.name = _studentNachnameTextfeld.text;
        student.hatBetrGrund = selectedBetreuungsgrund;        //Funzt trotzdem

        student.bild.vorschauData = _vorschauImageView.image;
         NSLog(@"Image Core Data: %@", _vorschauImageView.image);
         NSLog(@"Image Core Data DB: %@", student.bild.vorschauData);
         // NSLog(@"Betreuungsgrund: %@", student.hatBetrGrund);

        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];  // Eintrag in Datenbank
        [self.delegate AddStudentSavePressed:self];
        NSLog (@"Save Button bei AddBetrGrund pressed");            
        }
}

- (IBAction)albumButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (! [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] ) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Es steht kein Album zur Verfügung!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)kameraButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (! [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] ) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Es steht keine Kamera zur Verfügung!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)deleteBildPressed:(id)sender {
    self.vorschauImageView.image = nil;
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo 
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    _vorschauImageView.image = image;
    _vorschauImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // abgerundete Ecken
    NSLog(@"Image Vorschau: %@", _vorschauImageView.image);
}
```

Thanks in advance for ur help. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't save the image in Core Data. Instead, save it in a file on disk and save the path to the file in Core Data model.

This line:

```
student.bild.vorschauData = _vorschauImageView.image;
```

makes it look like the `student` has a relationship (`bild`) to some other object which contains the image. You need to create that object, insert it into the context and associated it with the `student` before you can use it.

Comment: Hello Wain, thank you very much for ur reply. I followed ur instruction and added this to my code:

        `Bild *pic = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Bild"
                                                            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

pic.vorschauData = _vorschauImageView.image

`
Now the app crashes and I get this error from the Log:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "vorschauData"; desired type = NSData; given type = UIImage;"

Comment: So you need to convert the image to data (JPEG or PNG). There are functions for that. Or make the attribute transformable instead of data.

Comment: thank you for ur reply. I just added this line:
`pic.vorschauData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_vorschauImageView.image);`

I will check if my CoreData contains the requested Data now. Thank u in advance for ur help :3 Please keep into account, that I cannot upvote any to ur comments due to low rep.

Comment: Remember you need to convert the data back into an image before you use it.

Comment: Cheers m8, I just checked the content of "pic.vorschauData" with NSLog and I saw this (see enclosed). Hope this is normal. Lol
http://image-upload.de/image/bXVFW7/36c6b9f3f1.png

Comment: Looks sensible. Remember you can always tick an answer to a question you asked ;-)

Comment: i really would love to upvote ur comments, I just need 5 more reppoints *sigh*